# Unable to make django-allauth work

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I was going thru the tutorial

`http://www.sarahhagstrom.com/2013/09/the-missing-django-allauth-tutorial/`

and got stuck at 1

```
UPDATE django_site SET DOMAIN = '127.0.0.1:8000', name ='Vort' WHERE id=1;
INSERT INTO socialaccount_socialapp (provider, name, secret, client_id,  `key`)
VALUES ("facebook", "Facebook", "--put-app-secret-here--", "--put-app-id-here--", '');
INSERT INTO socialaccount_socialapp_sites (socialapp_id, site_id) VALUES (1,1);`
```

I thought may be it will be a good idea to make these entries via 
`http://localhost:8000/admin/`

as shown below, but it doesn't work. Can someone tell me how to run above SQL or make entries via admin page?

[image]

Comment: It depends on your database. You can probably get access to the DB's cli  directly in your project by running `python manage.py shell`. Once there, you run the statements you have mentioned in your post.

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony `python manage.py shell` will drop you into a python shell. The scripts above are sql.

Comment: sorry, meant `python manage.py dbshell`

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony : when I run `manage.py dbshell` i get an error saying `'sqlite3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.``` Also, have you tried implementing it ? do you know any tutorial which works perfectly fine without breaking ?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it via shell, like Timmy O'Mahony suggested.

I didn't check the code so it might include typos but the idea would be:

Go to you project folder and start shell

```
python ./manage.py shell
```

Update Site and create a SocialApp

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
from allauth.socialaccount.models import SocialApp

site = Site.objects.get(pk=1)
site.domain = '127.0.0.1:8000'
site.name = 'Vort'
site.save()

app = SocialApp()
app.provider = 'facebook'
app.name = 'Facebook'
app.secret = '--put-app-secret-here--'
app.client_id = '--put-app-id-here--'
app.key = 'key'
app.save()

app.sites.add(site)
```

Comment: isn't this equivalent to doing it on admin page ? I still get an error when i try url `localhost:8000/accounts/login/`